# Pydantic BaseSettings cant find .env when running commands from different places

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic, alembic

So, Im trying to setup Alembic with FastAPI and Im having a problem with Pydantic's BaseSettings, I get a validation error (variables not found) because it doesnt find the .env file (?)

It can be solved by changing `env_file = ".env"` to `env_file = "../.env"` in the `BaseSettings` `class Config` but that makes the error happen when running main.py, I tried setting it as an absolute path with `env_file = os.path.abspath("../../.env")` but that didnt work.

What should I do?

config.py:

```
import os
from functools import lru_cache

from pydantic_settings import BaseSettings

abs_path_env = os.path.abspath("../../.env")


class Settings(BaseSettings):
    APP_NAME: str = "AppName"
    SQLALCHEMY_URL: str
    ENVIRONMENT: str

    class Config:
        env_file = ".env"  # Works with uvicorn run command from my-app/project/
        # env_file = "../.env"  Works with alembic command from my-app/alembic
        # env_file = abs_path_env

@lru_cache()
def get_settings():
    return Settings()
```

Project folders:

```
my-app
├── alembic
│   ├── versions
│   ├── alembic.ini
│   ├── env.py
│   ├── README
│   └── script.py.mako
├── project
│   ├── core
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── config.py
│   └── __init__.py
├── __init__.py
├── .env
└── main.py
```

Comment: The path is relative to the location of the working dir not the file itself. To make `.env` work you should just start all programs from `my-app`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For me it was the fact that `.env` was not in the same directory as the running script.

I had to manually anchor the `.env` file to an absolute path.

Here is my `settings.py` file with `.env` residing alongside in the same directory:

```
import os

from pydantic_settings import BaseSettings, SettingsConfigDict


DOTENV = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), ".env")


class Settings(BaseSettings):
    pg_dsn: str
    pg_pool_min_size: int
    pg_pool_max_size: int
    pg_pool_max_queries: int
    pg_pool_max_intactive_conn_lifetime: int

    model_config = SettingsConfigDict(env_file=DOTENV)
```

So with the `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), ".env")` line I basically instruct to search for `.env` file inside the same directory as the `settings.py` file.

This way you can run any of your scripts, and the `Settings` object will always point to your `.dotenv` file.

Answer (score 1):

on `pydantic 2.4.2`

this works for me:

`config.py`

```
from pydantic_settings import BaseSettings, SettingsConfigDict
from dotenv import find_dotenv, load_dotenv

load_dotenv(find_dotenv(".env"))

class Config(BaseSettings):
    ...
    
    model_config = SettingsConfigDict(case_sensitive=True)
```

I had to combine `python-dotenv`'s `load_env` and `find_dotenv`.

The `.env` file was in the parent directory of the `config.py`.